# excel vba copy and paste to fix "#REF" cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a checkbook register on excel 365. I am trying to add the feature of deleting a row(transaction) but when I run my vba code it errors out with the following:  Run-time error '1004': Paste method of worksheet class failed.

When I run my code to delete a row the balance column fills up with "#REF". My effort to fix this by copying the balance column and pasting it back after the row is deleted isn't working. Balance column still fills up with "#REF"s. Here is the code i'm using to copy and paste the balance column:

```
Sub DeleteTransactionRectangle_Click()
    Dim deletedRow

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    deletedRow = rng.Row

    MsgBox (deletedRow)
    Worksheets("Register").Range("I:I").Copy 
    rng.EntireRow.Delete

    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Register").Range("I:I")

End Sub
```

Anyone have any ideas to make this work.

Comment: What is the formula in column I?

Comment: =IF(F7<>"",I6-F7+H7,IF(H7 <> "",I6-F7+H7,""))                                                'f=payment  i=balance h=deposit

Answer (score 0):

You have dim 'rngg' but set 'rng' - should these not both be the same?

When you delete the row, it seems the copied information is lost from the clipboard. Instead, you could copy the formula from column I in the preceding row, and paste it back into the row you deleted:

```
rng.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("I" & deletedRow - 1).Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("I" & deletedRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch - that was from my edit, must have typed an extra g by mistake. Fixed... so that's not the issue.

Comment: Thank You your solution seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

### Deleting Rows Containing Formulas

[image]

**Tip**

In design mode, right-click on the command button and select `Properties`. Change `TakeFocusOnClick` to `False`, so when you click the command button it doesn't get selected (focus) but the selection on your sheet stays the same.

**Formula**

Your formula turns out to be bad when deleting rows. You could change it to:

```
=SUM(H$1:H2)-SUM(F$1:F2)
```

which is 'deleting columns proof'.

**Improve Code**

*To Study*

- [Range.Find
  method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)
- [Areas object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.areas)
- [Range.Areas property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas)
- [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)
- [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)
- [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)

Change the values in the constants section to fit your needs.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteTransactionRectangle_Click()

    Const rowFR As Long = 2       ' First Row of Data
    Const colFR As Long = 9       ' Formula Column

    Dim rowLR As Long             ' Last Row of Data
    Dim rng As Range              ' Current Area (For Each Control Variable)
    Dim rngTransAction As Range   ' Transaction (Column) Range
    Dim rngUnion As Range         ' Union Range
    Dim rngFinal As Range         ' Intersection (Final) Range

    ' Calculate Last Row of Data.
    rowLR = Columns(colFR).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ' From the selection, create Union Range which only contains cells
    ' of Formula Column, which will later be compared
    ' to Transaction (Column) Range.
    For Each rng In Selection.Areas
        If Not rngUnion Is Nothing Then
            Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, Cells(rng.Row, colFR) _
              .Resize(rng.Rows.Count))
        Else
            Set rngUnion = Cells(rng.Row, colFR).Resize(rng.Rows.Count)
        End If
    Next

    ' Define Transaction (Column) Range.
    Set rngTransAction = Cells(rowFR, colFR).Resize(rowLR - rowFR + 1)

    ' Create Intersection (Final) Range which will 'eliminate'
    ' all 'non-valid' areas of the Selection Range. 'Non-valid' areas are
    ' the ones before First Row of Data and after Last Row of Data.
    If Not rngUnion Is Nothing Then Set rngFinal _
      = Intersect(rngUnion, rngTransAction)

    ' Delete rows of Intersection (Final) Range.
    If Not rngFinal Is Nothing Then rngFinal.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your work on it. I think as more of a beginner I will stick with what I have, but the code probably would be worth studying at some point. I'm more interested in just getting my spreadsheet into usable form at this point.